# Since Array does not have For-each is there an alternate way we can use LINQ to do some action

Tags: c#, linq

`svc_Orders` is an array of `SVCORDER[]`

```
List<Order> local_order_list  = new List<Order>();

foreach (var svc_Order in svc_Orders)
{
    Order local_Order = new Order();
    //Converting SVCORDER to Order
    local_Order_list.Add(local_Order);
}
```

Now I am looping through the svc_order returned from the service converting them and `Order` adding them to list. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You're not "converting" them at all - you're just creating a list with the same size as `svc_Orders`, where each element is a new, empty `Order`. Now would also be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to project items from one type to another, that's what `Select` is for - then there's the `ToList` method:

```
// Names changed to conform to .NET conventions
var localOrderList = serviceOrders.Select(serviceOrder => new Order { ... })
                                  .ToList();
```

(We don't know what goes in the `...` as you haven't told us how you'd convert from `SVCORDER` to `Order`. You may want to turn that into a method to call from `Select`...)

Comment: Thanks, If svc_Orders  were a List , I might have prefered using foreach for doing the converstion. I mean if we can do the same stuff using select , then why do we  need foreach?

Comment: @Simsons: You don't need `ForEach`, and I'd encourage you to use LINQ instead. It's almost always cleaner. If you want to do something with each item in a collection, use a `foreach` loop - that's what it's there for. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Select` which is good for transforming things instead of `ForEach`, which is good for acting on items:

```
private Order MakeFromSvcOrder(SvcOrder ord) {
    // Do the conversion here
}
...
List<Order> local_order_list = svc_Orders.Select(MakeFromSvcOrder).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to SVCOrder to Order in select statement of LINQ and then create Order list
For example,

```
    List<Order> local_order_list = new List<Order>();    

    local_order_list = svc_Orders
.Select<SVCORDER, Order>(svcorder => new Order{} /*Convert SVCORDER to Order */)
.ToList<Order>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using a wcf service reference, but if you do:

1. Right click on the service reference and take "Configure Service Reference..."
2. There you can change the data type returned to a System.Collections.Generic.List.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could convert to List beforehand, and then use ConvertAll.

```
List<Order> local_order_list  = svc_Orders.ToList()
                                          .ConvertAll(svc_Order => new Order() { ... });
```

The downside is, whichever way you use Linq will involve generating an intermediate datastructure, which is immediately thrown away:

```
Select().ToList()       // select object, constant size
ToList().ConvertAll()   // whole list, same size as the array
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "an intermediate datastructure"? The `Select(...).ToList(...)` option is lazy, unlike `ToList().ConvertAll(...)`. The latter really does populate a whole collection pointlessly.

Comment: That lazy thing you are talking about, is an intermediate datastructure - objects created just to pass information around.

Comment: Yes, but there's a very significant difference in the requirements of the two approaches (one copying the whole collection, the other not) which your answer seems to ignore - it gives the impression that they're pretty much equivalent. The data structure in the Select approach is constant size (and small), and therefore negligible in almost all cases, I'd say. If you're trying to avoid every single allocation of anything, C# is usually the wrong language to use.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I agree with your comment.